# Update NSTableView based on Menu Item

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to update a Table View with something selected from a Menu Item. This is my AppDelegate class tied to NSArrayController.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];

    // An NSMutableArray to hold several Package objects
    self.allPackages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    Package *package = [[Package alloc] init];
    // Objective-C setters
    [package setName:@"Installation Core"];
    [package setCreator:@"Messi"];

    [self.allPackages insertObject:package atIndex:[self.allPackages count]];

    return self;
}
```

The NSArrayController is updating the NSTableView as expected upon init. Now I have a Menu Item which is calling a method to get some Package objects in a NSArrayController.

```
- (IBAction)open:(id)sender{

    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
.... 
    // If OK Button was pressed
    if([openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton){

        NSURL *url = [openDlg URL];

        PackageHelper *packageHelper = [[PackageHelper alloc] init];

        NSMutableArray *files = [packageHelper getFilesFromDirectory: url];

        NSLog(@"Received %li",files.count);
        // This is actually listing all the files I need.

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Pressed Cancel");
    }

}
```

Now my question is How do I get this NSMutableArray files show up on the TableView ? In other words, can the Array Controller get the data from the init method in the AppDelegate class and the open method on different class ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What class is `open:` in?  Generally you'd pass around either a pointer to the array controller or a pointer to the file array depending on which makes more sense.  But it's hard to tell w/o more context.

Comment: I have the open: in the AppDelegate Class, same as the init. I couldnt get the ArrayController pick the  changes to the Array. So I went ahead and added Core Data to the application. Now all is well.

Thanks